# TV episode where family survives explosion in cave, everything else dead

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'm trying to find out a sci-fi TV episode from the late 1950's to early 1960's.  It involved a family traveling and somehow an explosion happened. This forced them to take shelter in a cave. The next morning they woke up and when they exited the cave there were no signs of life, no birds chirping, etc. The family walked to the nearest town and they were greeted with overturned cars and buses and the people were all clothed skeletons.  Anyone know what series or show this was from?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Can you remember any more details about this series? What language was it in? What country was it made in? Please [edit] in anything you can remember - every little detail could help. You might also like to check out [our guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) on asking story-ID questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51262/please-help-identify-disaster-movie

Answer (score 9):

["Where Have All The People Gone?"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072400/), starring the great Peter Graves.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_Have_All_The_People_Gone%3F):

> On a camping trip in the Sierra Nevada mountains in central California, a father (Peter Graves) and his two teenage children are exploring a cave when they experience an earthquake. After emerging, they hear from a ranch hand who was outside that there was a bright solar flash prior to the earthquake. He soon falls ill and dies, whereupon his body turns to a powdery substance. As the family comes down from the mountain to the nearest town, they discover that everyone has turned to the powdery substance inside their clothing - and there are only a few survivors left.

I remember the scene when the family get back to town, and all the dead bodies are just piles of white powder inside their clothes. It creeped me out.

The entire movie is available on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udQN9k3erD4).